# Not able to redirect sales_order_create/index after login

Tags: magento-enterprise

I have an event observer (`admin_session_user_login_success`) for redirecting the page to `sales_order_create/index` controller after the login action. When i login as a user, the page is redirected to `sales_order/index` page.

I need to redirect `sales_order_create/index` after login.

**Config.xml**

```
<events>
  <admin_session_user_login_success>
    <observers>
      <vtrio_offlineorder_login>
          <class>Vtrio_OfflineOrder_Model_Observer</class> 
          <method>offlineuserRedirect</method>
          <type>singleton</type>
      </vtrio_offlineorder_login>
    </observers>
  </admin_session_user_login_success>
</events>
```

**Observer.php**

```
public function offlineuserRedirect($observer)
 {

   $link = "http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/admin/sales_order_create/index/";
   header("Location: $link");
   exit();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to redirect to the `sales_order_create/index`

```
Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl("adminhtml/sales_order_create/index"));
```

Comment: It is still redirected to sales_order/index page